# How to implement HashBang urls in Sencha Touch V2

Tags: navigation, sencha-touch-2

I'm working through my ST2 app, and decided that we need to implement url navigation... by this I mean, I want HashBang urls included so that I can jump to a specific view.

IE:
http://example.com/#!/home/index
http://example.com/#!/more/index

Here's a snippet of my app, and I'm hoping for some instruction on adding this feature.

**App/Index.js**

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({
    enabled: true,
    disableCaching: true // Todo: Switch to 'false' for production.,
});
Ext.application({

    name: 'rpc',
    appFolder: 'app',
    controllers: [
        'home',
        'bible', 
        'video',
        'contact',
        'more'
    ], 
    launch: function () {

        console.log('Ext.application ~ launch'),
        Ext.create('Ext.TabPanel', {
            fullscreen: true,
            tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
            items: [{
                title: 'Home',
                iconCls: 'home',
                xtype: 'home-indexView'
            }, {
                title: 'More',
                iconCls: 'more',
                xtype: 'more-indexView'
            }]
        });
    },
    initialize: function() {
        console.log('Ext.application ~ initialize');
        this.callParent();
    }
});
```

**App/Controllers/HomeController.js**

```
[PHP]Ext.define('rpc.controller.home', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    views: ['home.indexView'],
    stores: [],
    refs: [],
    
    init: function () {
        console.log('rpc.controller.home ~ init');
    },

    index: function () {
        console.log('rpc.controller.home ~ index');
    }
});
```

**App/Views/Home/indexView.js**

```
Ext.define('rpc.view.home.indexView', {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.home-indexView',
    config: {
       scrollable: true,
        items: [{
            xtype: 'toolbar',
            title: 'RockPointe Mobile',
            docked: 'top'
        }, {
            xtype: 'panel',
            cls: 'rpc-outerPanelWrapper',
            items: [{
               xtype: 'panel',
               cls: 'x-panel-rpc',
               items: [{
                   html: '<h1>RockPointe Church</h1><i>Home Page...</i>'
               }]
            }]
        }]
    },
    initialize: function () {
        console.log('rpc.view.home.indexView ~ initialize');
        this.callParent();
    }
});
```

Now the added trick to this is that I'd like it so that every time a view is loaded, it saves the url to the local storage so that the next time someone opens up the app, they are returned to their last page.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

#### note:

I don't need this to work at all with search engine optimization.

Answer (score 0):

Sencha Touch 2 controllers have the `routes` config option for defining hash bang routes. [Sencha Docs - Controller](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.app.Controller-cfg-routes)